# Calling R script from Java using Renjin and pass binary as parameter

Tags: java, r, dataframe, renjin

We have Java web application running in Tomcat. We want to integrate R scripts (code already exist) into our application and planning to use Renjin to accomplish that. We will crate simple UI where the User can select and upload couple of files (csv, excel) to the server and then we need to pass that data to R script.
I am new to R and Renjin and evaluating some options:
Can we pass binary data from Java to R using Vector raw data?
or we have to create Data Frame for ex. in Java and pass that to R script?
or is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks.